# rsync a directory with its own descendant

Tags: rsync

**tl;dr:** I want to `rsync` a directory to its own descendant, and then `rsync` the said descendant back to the original directory--including deletions and exclusions in both directions.

Before you ask the obvious question, "Why would you want to do that?" or point out how much better another approach would be, this is a business requirement. It's not my choice, and I'm aware of the risks, so just indulge me. I do not intend to justify the approach any further.

**Details:**

I want to `rsync` a directory to its own descendant--i.e., a directory "underneath" or "inside" it, like `parent` to `parent/child`, for example--and then sync changes to the descendant back to the original directory, e.g., `parent/child` to `parent`, including deletions and exclusions in both directions. Visually, I need to do this:

```
parent -> parent/child
parent <- parent/child
```

The difficulties are to...

1. Prevent infinite recursion when going from the ancestor to the descendant
2. Not delete the source files mid-operation when syncing the descendant back to its ancestor (manifested as "file has vanished" errors)
3. Respect the exclusions all the while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three parts to the solution. In order...

1. Exclude the descendant directory path *relative to the ancestor*, e.g., `child` when syncing from `parent/child`
2. Use the `--delete-after` flag instead of  `--delete`
3. Make all exclusion paths relative to the source, e.g., `exclude.txt` as opposed to `/var/www/parent/exclude.txt`

Here's a test script (with some special formatting for nicer output):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

clear

printf "\n\e[33mrsync version:\n"
printf "%s--------------\e[39m\n"

rsync --version | head -n 1
# rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29

rm -r parent

mkdir -p parent

touch parent/original.txt \
      parent/delete-from-child.txt \
      parent/exclude-from-child.txt

printf "\n\e[33mOriginal state:\n"
printf "%s---------------\e[39m\n"

tree -a --noreport -- parent

printf "\n\e[33mrsync to child:\n"
printf "%s---------------\e[39m\n"

printf "rsync --archive \\n      --delete-after \\n      --exclude=exclude-from-child.txt \\n      "$PWD"/parent/ \\n      "$PWD"/parent/child\n\n"
rsync --archive \
      --delete-after \
      --exclude=exclude-from-child.txt \
      "$PWD"/parent/ \
      "$PWD"/parent/child

tree -a --noreport -- parent; echo

printf "\e[33mMake changes:\n"
printf "%s---------------\e[39m\n"

rm parent/child/delete-from-child.txt
printf "rm parent/child/delete-from-child.txt\n"
touch parent/child/create-in-child.txt
printf "touch parent/child/create-in-child.txt\n"
touch parent/child/exclude-from-parent.txt
printf "touch parent/child/exclude-from-parent.txt\n\n"

printf "\e[33mrsync back to parent:\n"
printf "%s---------------------\e[39m\n"

printf "rsync --archive \\n      --delete-after \\n      --exclude=child \\n      --exclude=exclude-from-child.txt \\n      --exclude=exclude-from-parent.txt \\n      "$PWD"/parent/child/ \\n      "$PWD"/parent\n\n"
rsync --archive \
      --delete-after \
      --exclude=child \
      --exclude=exclude-from-child.txt \
      --exclude=exclude-from-parent.txt \
      "$PWD"/parent/child/ \
      "$PWD"/parent

tree -a --noreport -- parent; echo
# Or `find parent -type f; echo`, if you don't have `tree`

printf "%s\n\e[33mFinal comparison:\n"
printf "%s-----------------\e[39m\n"

diff --exclude=child parent parent/child; echo
```

Output:

```
rsync version:
--------------
rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29

Original state:
---------------
parent
├── delete-from-child.txt
├── exclude-from-child.txt
└── original.txt

rsync to child:
---------------
rsync --archive
      --delete-after
      --exclude=exclude-from-child.txt
      /var/www/parent/
      /var/www/parent/child

parent
├── child
│   ├── delete-from-child.txt
│   └── original.txt
├── delete-from-child.txt
├── exclude-from-child.txt
└── original.txt

Make changes:
---------------
rm parent/child/delete-from-child.txt
touch parent/child/create-in-child.txt
touch parent/child/exclude-from-parent.txt

rsync back to parent:
---------------------
rsync --archive
      --delete-after
      --exclude=child
      --exclude=exclude-from-child.txt
      --exclude=exclude-from-parent.txt
      /var/www/parent/child/
      /var/www/parent

parent
├── child
│   ├── create-in-child.txt
│   ├── exclude-from-parent.txt
│   └── original.txt
├── create-in-child.txt
├── exclude-from-child.txt
└── original.txt


Final comparison:
-----------------
Only in parent: exclude-from-child.txt
Only in parent/child: exclude-from-parent.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to set up bind mounts and thus make the two trees appear independent, then rsync as normal:

```
mkdir /mnt/parent
mkdir /mnt/child
mkdir /mnt/empty
mount --bind /path/to/parent/child /mnt/child
mount --bind /path/to/parent /mnt/parent
mount --bind /mnt/empty /mnt/parent/child
```

Now, when you do

```
rsync [args] /mnt/parent/. /mnt/child/.
```

the empty directory `/mnt/empty` will mask the real `/path/to/parent/child` directory; `/mnt/parent/child` will appear empty and will avoid infinite recursion.

When you do

```
rsync [args] /mnt/child/. /mnt/parent/.
```

the situation will be similar; `/mnt/child/child/` will be empty (since you don't copy anything there in the first place), and `/mnt/parent/child/` will also appear empty, so there is no risk of deleting anything from there.

This is perhaps less elegant than @TravisCarden's solution, but possibly more robust.

Comment: How interesting! Unfortunately, I can't count on my particular target audience having access to mount or I would try this, but thanks for the idea!